# Can anyone help me compute the partial derivatives of the following vector equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have the following:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{u} = \frac{(\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{c})\times\mathbf{n}}{\sqrt{(\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{c})\!\cdot\!(\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{c})}}
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{c}$ is a constant vector and $\mathbf{n}$ is defined as

\begin{align}
\mathbf{n}(\theta,\phi) = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\theta\sin\phi \\
    \sin\theta\sin\phi \\
    \cos\phi
  \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}

Can anyone help me find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \theta}$, $\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \phi}$, $\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{u}}{\ \partial \theta^2}$, and $\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{u}}{\ \partial \phi^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
\begin{equation}
(f g^{-1/2})' = f' g^{-1/2} - \frac{1}{2}f g^{-3/2} g'
\end{equation}